# Changing filters from Select to simple input

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, doctrine

in my filter forms I want to change the default `sfWidgetDoctrineChoice` to a simple `sfWidgetFormFilterInput`.
For the relational fields (e.g. UserForm has a field PhoneNumberListId).

*What's the purpose?*

***=>*** When you have a lot of relational data symfony (to be exactly the DoctrineFormChoice widget) will render a select element containing all(!) possible relations, causing the website to crash.

**An example to light things up:**

Tables: User, PhonenumberList
Form: UserFilterForm

Basically we would have this code in the UserFilterForm:

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
'phonenumber_list_id' => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('PhonenumberList'), 'add_empty' => true))));
```

I change this to:

```
$this->setWidget('phonenumber_list_id', new sfWidgetFormFilterInput(array('with_empty' => false)));
        $this->setValidator('phonenumber_list_id', new sfValidatorSchemaFilter('text', new sfValidatorNumber(array('required' => false))));
```

**What effect does this have on the form rendering?**

The formerly select:

```
<select name="user_filters[phonenumber_list_id]">
```

Will change to:

```
<input name="user_filters[phonenumber_list_id][text]" >
```

Which I causing the following (to me unexplainable) error/exception:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
at Doctrine_Connection->execute('SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_results FROM receipt r WHERE r.partner_id IN (?) AND (r.deleted_at IS NULL)', array('text' => 1))
```

**Notice: receipt≘user, partner_id≘phonenumber_list**

*the sign "≘" explained over here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign (Example "A ≘ B", in words "A is like/is a synonym for B")